# Removing duplicate elements by their attributes in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Is there a nice way to remove elements from a list,  by their attributes?

Example:

```
lis = [['element1', 12], ['element2', 2], ['element3', 12], ['element4', 36], ['element5', 12]]
```

And I want to get this list:

```
new_lis = [['element1', 12], ['element2', 2], ['element4', 36]]
```

I am looking for a short and elegant solution, maybe a module I am not familiar with?

Comment: you want to remove duplicates by the `[1]` item from the main list?

Comment: What decides whether you want to keep `element1` or `element3` in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: The removal should be done by a sub element of the inner lists

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is using [simple generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) function. The reason is that [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-generator) is lazy evaluated which means that it produces the item in the list on demand; saves a lot of memory for large list. You can then iterate the generator object and *do something with the item*

Demo:

```
>>> lis = [['element1', 12], ['element2', 2], ['element3', 12], ['element4', 36], ['element5', 12]]
>>> def deduplicate(items):
...     seen = set()
...     for item in items:
...         if not item[1] in seen:
...             seen.add(item[1])
...             yield item
... 
>>> deduplicate(lis)
<generator object deduplicate at 0x7fd454352e08>
>>> for item in deduplicate(lis):
...     print(item)
... 
['element1', 12]
['element2', 2]
['element4', 36]
>>> list(deduplicate(lis))
[['element1', 12], ['element2', 2], ['element4', 36]]
```

Comment: Why is the best way a generator when OP wants a list? Honest question.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function for this:

```
def remove_duplicates_n(lis, n):
    'returns new list with items from lis and duplicates at position n removed, keeps order'
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in lis:
        if item[n] not in seen:
            result.append(item)
            seen.add(item[n])
    return result
```

For your desired result, call `remove_duplicates_n(lis, 1)`.

Bonus: if you want to go to the dark side of sideeffects...

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in lis if x[1] not in seen and not seen.add(x[1])]
[['element1', 12], ['element2', 2], ['element4', 36]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal for a one-liner

```py
{key(elt): elt for elt in reversed(iterable)}.values()
```

The order of the iterable is not kept because of the `reversed` call, but without it the later duplicate elements would override the earliest ones. Might need to be adjusted depending on your constraints.
Can be used like so, with the example given in the question:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Callable, TypeVar
from operator import itemgetter

T = TypeVar("T")

def get_unique_elements(iterable: Iterable[T], key: Callable[[T], any]) -> Iterable[T]:
    """
    Returns all unique elements from an iterable,
    using the key function to establish unicity.
    Elements appearing first will have priority in case of duplicates
    """
    return {key(elt): elt for elt in reversed(iterable)}.values()

list(get_unique_elements(
    [
        ["element1", 12],
        ["element2", 2],
        ["element3", 12],
        ["element4", 36],
        ["element5", 12],
    ],
    key=itemgetter(1),
)
```

`Out: [['element1', 12], ['element4', 36], ['element2', 2]]`